# How i can define a function in script?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, localization

I'm using a function in my app.js to translate my Vue component and get Laravel lang file`Vue.prototype.trans = local => _.get(window.i18n, local)`
this function is work in my HTML template and didn't work in my script.

```
return '<span class="label label-danger">' + trans('attendance.Absent') + '</span>';
```

I got this error when is use this function in script`Uncaught ReferenceError: trans is not defined`

and this function didn't work when I use Vue Router package.

This route to get all fils lang in view to import it in lang.js

```
Route::get('/js/lang.js', function () {
    $strings = Cache::remember('lang.js', 0.01, function () {
        $lang = Auth::user()->settings;
        $files   = glob(resource_path('lang/' . $lang['locale'] . '/*.php'));
        $strings = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name           = basename($file, '.php');
            $strings[$name] = require $file;
        }

        return $strings;
    });

    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo('window.i18n = ' . json_encode($strings) . ';');
    exit();
})->name('assets.lang');
```

Comment: It would be `this.trans` in your script.

Comment: and what about Vue router problem when i enter in any route it not display any translate lang al is empty and when i make any action like click on button al the work is display.